# ExpressionVisitor doesn't have it's VisitMethodCall invoked

Tags: c#, linq, expression, .net-core, expressionvisitor

I am following an [example series on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii.aspx) for creating a LINQ Provider and have hit a wall.

I am expecting that when I write the following test that the `ExpressionVisitor` sub-class in the source-code below has it's `VisitMethodCall` invoked.

```
[Fact]
public void DatabaseModeler_provides_table_modeler()
{
    var q = new LightmapQuery<AspNetRoles>(new SqliteProvider2());
    q.Where(role => role.Name == "Admin");
    var result = q.ToList();
}
```

What happens instead is that the `VisitConstant` method is invoked. I assume this is because when the `Provider` is instanced, it assigns it's `Expression` property a `ConstantExpression`. I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong or if the guide on MSDN has issues with it preventing me from getting the expression containing the `Where` method invocation.

This is the source code I have for the `IQueryable<T>` and `IQueryProvider` implementations.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace Lightmap.Querying
{
    internal class SqliteQueryTranslator : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        internal StringBuilder queryBuilder;

        internal string Translate(Expression expression)
        {
            this.queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            this.Visit(expression);
            return this.queryBuilder.ToString();
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            return base.Visit(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Method.DeclaringType != typeof(IQueryable) && node.Method.Name != nameof(Enumerable.Where))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException($"The {node.Method.Name} method is not supported.");
            }

            this.queryBuilder.Append($"SELECT * FROM {node.Method.DeclaringType.Name}");
            return node;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
        {
            return node;
        }

        private static Expression StripQuotes(Expression expression)
        {
            while (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Quote)
            {
                expression = ((UnaryExpression)expression).Operand;
            }

            return expression;
        }
    }

    public abstract class LightmapProvider : IQueryProvider
    {
        public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
        {
            Type genericParameter = expression.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
            return (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(LightmapQuery<>)
                .MakeGenericType(genericParameter), new object[] { this, expression });
        }

        public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression) => new LightmapQuery<TElement>(this, expression);

        object IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
        {
            return this.Execute(expression);
        }

        public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
        {
            return (TResult)this.Execute(expression);
        }

        public abstract string GetQueryText(Expression expression);

        public abstract object Execute(Expression expression);
    }

    public class SqliteProvider2 : LightmapProvider
    {
        public override object Execute(Expression expression)
        {
            var x = new SqliteQueryTranslator().Translate(expression);
            return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(TypeCache.GetGenericParameter(expression.Type, t => true)));
        }

        public override string GetQueryText(Expression expression)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class LightmapQuery<TTable> : IOrderedQueryable<TTable>
    {
        public LightmapQuery(IQueryProvider provider)
        {
            this.Provider = provider;
            this.Expression = Expression.Constant(this);
        }

        public LightmapQuery(IQueryProvider provider, Expression expression)
        {
            if (!typeof(IQueryable<TTable>).IsAssignableFrom(expression.Type))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            this.Expression = expression;
            this.Provider = provider;
        }

        public Type ElementType => typeof(TTable);

        public Expression Expression { get; }

        public IQueryProvider Provider { get; }

        public IEnumerator<TTable> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (this.Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<TTable>>(Expression)).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (Provider.Execute<IEnumerable>(Expression)).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

Having updated my unit test to actually store the `IQueryable` from the `.Where`, I'm still not seeing my `VisitMethodCall` invoked.

```
[Fact]
public void DatabaseModeler_provides_table_modeler()
{
    var q = new LightmapQuery<AspNetRoles>(new SqliteProvider2())
        .Where(role => role.Name == "Admin");
    var result = q.ToList();
}
```

Comment: You just slipped in not using the `q.Where(role => role.Name == "Admin");` but calling `ToList()` on the original `q`.

Comment: That's a good catch; doesn't fix my issue though. I updated my OP to reflect this change, however my `VisitMethodCall` is still never hit

Comment: Are you using the `ExpressionVisitor` class mentioned in the article you referred? This class is now public under `System.Linq.Expressions` must have been updated ever since. This might be the reason why `VisitMethodCall` is not being called.

Comment: I am using the .Net expressions class and not the MSDN one. I haven't been able to track down much in the way of using the .Net flavor after it was released. All of the examples or blog posts I've seen roll their own which I was avoiding

Comment: I'm using this under the dotnet5.4 framework as part of the .net Core bits.

Comment: What does `q.ToString()` display?

Comment: @JonHanna It displays an empty string. This was compiled against `dotnet5.4` with .Net Core. I moved this exact code over to a new .net 4.5 project and the `VisitMethodCall` method was hit without issue. This seems to be specific to the new .Net Core stuff.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger I was going to post the same as your last comment. But since everything starts in your `Translate` method, you might check the type of the passed expression and debug step by step what's going on.

Comment: The Type passed into my `Translate` is a `ConstantExpression` and the `Translate` method is only ever called once.

Comment: @JonHanna In the `dotnet5.4 CoreFX` project it comes through as a `ConstantExpression`. In the `.net 4.5` project it comes through the `Translate` method as a `MethodCallExpression`.

Comment: @JonHanna I figured this out and posted an answer. Turns out to be an assembly reference issue.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error and a bit of help in IRC, I was able to identify the problem and resolve it. The issue was that my unit test project, which was a .Net Core project, did not have a reference to the `System.Linq.Queryable` assembly.

In my unit test

```
[Fact]
public void DatabaseModeler_provides_table_modeler()
{
    var q = new LightmapQuery<AspNetRoles>(new SqliteProvider2());
    var q2 = q.Where(role => role.Name == "Admin");
    var result = q2.ToList();
}
```

The `Type` of `q2` is `"WhereEnumerableIterator'1"` which made us realize that it wasn't returning an `IQueryable`.

[image]

After adding the above reference to the `project.json`, the `Type` of `q2` turned into `"LightmapQuery'1"` like I was expecting. With this, my `VisitMethodCall` method gets hit without issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is trivial - you forgot to assign the result of applying `Where`:

```
q.Where(role => role.Name == "Admin");
```

use something like this instead

```
var q = new LightmapQuery<AspNetRoles>(new SqliteProvider2())
    .Where(role => role.Name == "Admin");
var result = q.ToList();
```

Comment: I updated my unit test as you showed; my `VisitMethodCall` still does not get hit though. I've got a break point set on it and the `VisitConstant` with only the `VisitConstant` ever being hit. I've updated my OP to show my revised unit test.